# 'object' does not contain a definition for ExecuteNonQuery error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a C# website wherein I have to dynamically create a table in the database with the same name as the username given by the user at the time of registration.

my code looks like this:

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = txtName.Text;
    string uname = txtUname.Text;
    string mail = txtMail.Text;
    string country = txtCountry.Text;
    string pass = txtPassword.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=XYZ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FileHost;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO register(name,username,mail_id,country,password) values('" + name + "','" + uname + "','" + mail + "','"+country+"','"+pass+"')", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    string sql = "CREATE TABLE 'txtUname.Text'" +
        "(uname VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT PkeyMyId PRIMARY KEY, " + "fname VARCHAR(50), path VARCHAR(255))";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    message.Text = "Registration Successfull!!!";
    txtName.Text = "";
    txtUname.Text = "";
    txtMail.Text = "";
    txtCountry.Text = "";
}
```

But I receive an error:

> `object` does not contain a definition for `ExecuteNonQuery` and no extension method `ExecuteNonQuery` accepting a first argument of type `object` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) at the line: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Show how you declare `cmd`. It looks like it is declared as `object cmd`.

Comment: private object cmd; I've declared it right after the class

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: So, the compiler is right - there is no such method `object.ExecuteNonQuery`. `ExecuteNonQuery` is a part of `SqlCommand`. Declare your variable as `private SqlCommand cmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you declare your `cmd` as an `object`, compiler is absolutely right:

```
private object cmd;
// ...
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // "object" has no "ExecuteNonQuery" method
```

Declare your variable as `SqlCommand`:

```
private SqlCommand cmd;
```

Comment: I tried that but it throws me an exception: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'txtUname.Text'

Comment: @BijoyJoseph Exception means that the problem "does not contain" has been fixed and it compiles. `SqlException` is absolutely another error and does not belong to this question :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix many things. First of all, you have to make your query correct.

```
string sql = "CREATE TABLE 'txtUname.Text'" +
    "(uname VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT PkeyMyId PRIMARY KEY, " + "fname VARCHAR(50), path VARCHAR(255))";
```

change to

```
string sql = "CREATE TABLE ["+txtUname.Text+"] +
    "(uname VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT PkeyMyId PRIMARY KEY, fname VARCHAR(50), path VARCHAR(255))";
```

Comment: in your query you are creating table called *'txtUname.Text'*, that's why error naturally gonna be occur

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
`using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con)){
     //put your stuff here 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }`
```